# Linux wifi extract script

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, wifi, extract

I just wrote a script that extracts wifi passwords from the system, how can I improve that script and make it cleaner ?

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import os


file_path = "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/"
wifi_data = os.listdir(file_path)
print("    ")
data = []
for file in wifi_data:
    spaceless_wifi_path_data  = file.replace(" ", "\\ ")
    cmd = f"cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/{spaceless_wifi_path_data}"
    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(args,
              stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    data.append(p)

parsed_data = str([data[i].communicate() for i in range(len(data))]).split("\\")
wifi_id_list = [line[4:] for line in parsed_data if 'nid' in line]


keys = [keys[5:] for keys in parsed_data if "npsk" in keys]


gap = len(wifi_id_list) - len(keys)


for missing in range(gap):
    keys.append("No keys has found")


results = list(zip(wifi_id_list[::-1], keys))


for ID, PASS in results:
    print(f"WiFi ID: {ID},  Password: {PASS}")
```

How this code can improved in terms of less used variables and more list comprehensions. It just feels like not convineant to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use cat and start a subprocess to read the content of a file. This simplifies the script a bit. I also think that list comprehension isn't suited for this task and you should just build the result while iterating over the files.

```
import os
path = "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/"
wifi_id = []
keys = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(path + file, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        for line in content.split('\n'):
            if line.startswith("nid"):
                wifi_id.append(line[4:])
            if line.startswith("npsk"):
                keys.append(line[5:])
        if len(keys) != len(wifi_id):
            keys.append("Keys not found")

results = list(zip(wifi_id, keys))
```